# Better way to query instead of looping through all data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following method that takes a 10 digit number and searches for matches:

```
  def self.get_agents_by_phone_number(phone_number)
        all_agents = Agent.all
        agents = Array.new
        all_agents.each do |a|
            if "1" + a.phone_number.scan(/\d/).join('').last(10) == phone_number
                agents << a
            end
        end
        return agents
  end
```

The catch is that the `phone_number` field in the DB have not been scrubbed and may be in a few different formats. Here is a sample:

```
2.5.3 :089 > Agent.all.pluck :phone_number
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "agents"."phone_number" FROM "agents"
 => ["1-214-496-5089", "193.539.7577", "557-095-1452", "(734) 535-5668", "(279) 691-4148", "(474) 777-3615", "137.158.9465", "(280) 680-8618", "296.094.7455", "1-500-079-7285", "1-246-171-1355", "1-444-626-9429", "(614) 603-6276", "594.170.4795", "1-535-859-1377", "676.706.4384", "256-312-4417", "1-592-904-2339", "174.912.8838", "677.137.7019", "319-013-7526", "(200) 790-1698", "576-106-0746", "(214) 042-9715", "(312) 188-5862", "1-823-392-9020", "663.331.4191", "237-101-0271", "1-836-465-1204", "394-499-0004", "713-068-1726", "1-223-484-7856"]
```

The method I shared above works but feels pretty inefficient. Any better ways of doing this without touching the data in the DB?

Comment: Why don't you save a clean version of the number? It's a lot easier to query and you can always reformat them again with a consistent look for display (it's weird to have some with dots, some with hypens, some with parentesses, some with spaces)

Comment: @arieljuod I agree, but not an option at the moment. I was just curious if there is a more efficient way to do this without touching the DB.

Comment: (not related to the problem) You can use `select` instead of `each` like this:
`all_agents.select { |a| "1" + a.phone_number.scan(/\d/).join('').last(10) == phone_number }`

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
#sample if incoming phone_num = "333.111.4444"
#You need to adjust it to possible ways and push to array.

options = Array.new
options << "1.333.111.4444"
options << "333.111.4444"
options << "1-333-111-4444"
options << "333-111-4444"
# and so on ...

# then query in where
Agent.where("phone_number IN (?)", options)
```

It's way better than looping, only you need to adjust the phone number to get better performance. I do not know, how big is your data but since you are fetching `.all` agents it could be huge :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use the `LIKE` operator with multiple '%' wildcards between digit.

```
phone_number = '1234567890'

# split the number in groups
last4 = phone_number[-4..-1] # 7890
middle3 = phone_number[-7..-5] # 456
first3or4 = phone_number[0..-8] # 123

# build the pattern
pattern = "#{first3or4}%#{middle3}%#{last4}" # 123%456%7890

# use it for LIKE query 
Agent.where('phone_number LIKE ?', pattern)
```

It won't be a fast query with all those wildcards.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like